# PHP Hashtag System

Tags: php, mysql, sql, twitter, hashtag

I'm trying to set up a hashtag system in PHP, where if the user input contains a `#` next to a word, it will be replaced with a link.

For example:

```
$input = "mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input'])";
$sql = "INSERT INTO table (input) VALUES ('$input')";
mysql_query($sql, $connect);
?>
<?php
mysql_select_db("database",$connect);
$sql = mysql_real_escape_string("SELECT * FROM input");
$myData = mysql_query($sql, $connect);
echo $myData;
```

where `$myData` says something like "Just went 80mph in a schoolzone #yolo"

I want it to echo out:

```
Just went 80mph in a schoolzone <a href="search?q=%23yolo">#yolo</a>
```

like on Twitter. I don't know how to set this up, but I assume `preg_match()` or `str_replace()` may be involved.

Comment: `$input = "mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['input'])";` Probably isn't what you want.

Comment: mysql_* functions are deprecated, consider using mysqli_* or PDO.

Comment: `$sql = mysql_real_escape_string("SELECT * FROM input");` There is no need to escape a static string, only ones which have been generated should have their inputs sanitised.

Comment: Please, seriously, stop using `mysql_query`. It's awful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The regex you're looking for is `#([^\s]+)` which matches one or more characters after a hash until white-space occurs. This can then be used with a preg_replace to create a link.

E.g.

```
$output = preg_replace( "/#([^\s]+)/", "<a href=\"search?q=%23$1\">#$1</a>", $input );
```